# Makefile directory usage

Tags: c++, makefile

I realise this is a commong query, but I've spent hours looking at previous answers but am still at a loss. I don't have a huge amount of experience with makefiles and am finding it difficult to follow the examples.

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=g++

CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS= -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello
FULLOBJS = $(addprefix obj/,$(OBJS))


all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) -MD -I. $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm -rf $(OBJS) $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)


-include $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)
```

Which works as I'd like. However, it would be even better if I was able to neatly organise the .h .cpp .o and .b files into /header/ /source/ and /object/ relative subdirectories. Please could you explain to me how to do so?

Thanks very much

Comment: Do you want to create separate folders for .h, .cpp, .o and add the path to these folders?

Comment: Yes if possible. I assume there is a better way than specifying the path strings for each file separately. And I also assume there is a way to place all .o and .d files created by the makefile into a specified directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For placing the .cpp files, VPATH is your friend, e.g.:

```
VPATH = ./src ./blah
```

... will cause the Makefile to look for your .cpp files in ./src and ./blah (instead of only in the directory where your Makefile is)

For .h files, you'll want to pass the compiler a flag telling it where to look for them, e.g.:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I./headers -I./blah
```

Ways to place .o files into a sub-folder can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639794/getting-make-to-create-object-files-in-a-specific-directory).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Didn't realise adding VPATH was as simple as that!