# Compile object files in local temporary directories

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I have a GNU Makefile project that has source files scattered throughout multiple directories, i.e.:

```
Project/common/base.c
Project/common/test.c
Project/delta/delta.c
Project/delta/bravo/alt.c
```

I would like to try two separate ways of generating the object files, and then
linking them:

**Type 1:**

```
ARCH=arm64
Project/common/base.c       ==>     Project/common/.tmp/${ARCH}/base.o
Project/common/test.c       ==>     Project/common/.tmp/${ARCH}/test.o
Project/delta/delta.c       ==>     Project/delta/.tmp/${ARCH}/delta.o
Project/delta/bravo/alt.c   ==>     Project/delta/bravo/.tmp/${ARCH}/alt.o
```

**Type 2:**

```
ARCH=arm64
Project/common/base.c       ==>     .tmp/${ARCH}/Project/common/base.o
Project/common/test.c       ==>     .tmp/${ARCH}/Project/common/test.o
Project/delta/delta.c       ==>     .tmp/${ARCH}/Project/delta/delta.o
Project/delta/bravo/alt.c   ==>     .tmp/${ARCH}/Project/delta/bravo/alt.o
```

How can I generate a build rule like this so that I can just add more source
files to a list, and have the build iterate through them, creating output/object
files with the file name patterns shown above, and then linking a final binary/app with the resulting object files? [I've tried a similar such
approach as described in another
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639794/getting-make-to-create-object-files-in-a-specific-directory),
but that one assumes all the source files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/how-to-place-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory), you could try the approach in the accepted answer for your second approach:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

and define `$(OBJDIR)` as `.tmp/${ARCH}`.

Comment: Typically, that's what `make` actually takes care of.  Do you have much experience with it?